# Ansible: How to conditional run if variable is stored in uppercase?

Tags: ansible, boolean

I am new to Ansible and try to run steps within an `ansible-playbook` on a conditional `when` clause.
The variable is set up with an Oracle SQL and filled with only uppercase correctly.

The check runs fine with :

```yaml
- name: Check CDB
  connection: local
  oracle_sql:
    hostname: "{{ db_hostname }}"
    service_name: "{{ rcs_db_service }}"
    user: "{{ db_connect_user }}"
    password: "{{ db_connect_password }}"
    mode: "{{ db_connect_mode }}"
    sql: "SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'enable_pluggable_database'"
  register: cdb_on
```

Result is:

```json
ok: [hostname] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "hostname": "hostname",
            "mode": "sysdba",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "port": "xxxx",
            "script": null,
            "service_name": "dbname",
            "sql": "SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'enable_pluggable_database'",
            "user": "SYS"
        }
    },
    "msg": [
        [
            "FALSE"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The (expected) Return Value of Oracle SQL task is "`FALSE`"

I tried different conditional runs like. It seems that Ansible can take the `FALSE` as boolean, but it does not work with

```yaml
- name: run
  when: cdb_on | bool == FALSE
```

as well if I've tried to use it as literal

```yaml
- name: run
  when: cdb_on == '"FALSE"'
```

or

```yaml
- name: run
  when: cdb_on | upper == "FALSE"
```

or

```yaml
- name: run
  when: cdb_on == 'FALSE'
```

Result is always the same - the next task / statement which should been run becomes always skipped. The playbook highlighted `FALSE` always in red as boolean.

How can I get the condition working as literal?

Different masking like shown above, need the condition with `FALSE` to get it run.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: "*How can I get the condition working?*"**

> *It seems that Ansible took the `FALSE` as boolean*

Right, it can. Therefore it is simpler, just [`bool` filter – cast into a boolean](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/bool_filter.html). The only were work will be necessary is the data structure of the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) of the [`oracle_sql`](https://github.com/oravirt/ansible-oracle-modules/blob/master/oracle_sql) module, since it's provide a [`msg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#msg) with a [list of list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables).

After

- [`flatten` filter – flatten lists within a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html)
- and [get the `first` element](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names) of the contained list only,

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    cdb_on:
      msg: [
        [
           "FALSE"
        ]
      ]

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "cdb_on.msg: {{ cdb_on.msg }} is of type {{ cdb_on.msg | type_debug }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "CDB is not ON!"
    when: not (cdb_on.msg | flatten | first ) | bool
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'cdb_on.msg: [[u''FALSE'']] is of type list'

TASK [debug] **************************************
  msg: CDB is not ON!
```

---

**Background Information**

According [`ansible/plugins/filter/core.py` - `to_bool`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L81) will cast everything to `False` which is not in

```python
    if isinstance(a, string_types):
        a = a.lower()
    if a in ('yes', 'on', '1', 'true', 1):
        return True
    return False
```

so even such thing like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

     VAR: "TEST"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "VAR: {{ VAR }} is of type {{ VAR | type_debug }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "Value is not True!"
    when: not VAR | bool
```

will result into

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 'VAR: TEST is of type AnsibleUnicode'

TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Value is not True!
```

See also [Boolean variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#boolean-variables).